# Difference in parsing [FromBody] param between MVC project and Web API project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

One of my co-workers tapped me earlier to help him look into an odd behavior he was seeing with a Web API controller function.  The method looks like this.

```
// api/cart?channel=123&qsaid=456
public void Post(string channel, string qsaid, [FromBody]CartDTO postedData)
{
    string message = string.Empty;
    if (postedData == null)
    {
        message = string.Format("POST data is missing");
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, message));
    }
}
```

In any event, the "postedData" parameter was always coming up null (we wrote that exception in just to mess with it).  This is just a simple class with some string properties that is passed in as JSON via the POST body.  There were a number of questions on this subject on SO and elsewhere, with various resolutions, but none seemed to be working.

I grabbed a copy of his project and saw for myself the behavior, and tried some of the above suggested resolutions to no effect.  Eventually I noticed that he'd stood up this project as an MVC 4 project and had made the Web API controller as part of it (though the project is just going to be services, no front end).

Troubleshooting, I created my own project starting with a blank ASP.NET Web Application and checked the box to include Web API components - then pasted the controller into my project and changed the namespace, along with the definition of the complex object.

Changed my Fiddler2 endpoint to point to the new project - and it worked.  The object was coming through correctly and all its properties were assigned.

I have no explanation other than the project itself was created as MVC4 vs a blank web application with the Web API components.  My question is - is there some functional difference in how these project types handle controller parameters (specifically complex types from the body of a post)  - or was something else screwing with us that I somehow shed in changing the project type?

Comment: [Here is a great explanation by another StackOverflow user](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27078374/636942)

Comment: [Even better official MS explanation!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx)