# Cannot POST api call from .net core MVC

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following code in my .net core MVC application:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public void GetCustomerInfo([FromBody] string value)
 {
       string data = value;
 }
```

after deploy this to my azure we app and call 'azuresiteurl/api/controller/GetCustomerInfo' page not found error occurs.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: GetCustomerInfo which is a post. Just to rule out the obvious, you are doing a post request? Loading a page is a get request. Also Api endpoint naming suggests GET (would propose to refactor that from a api design standpoint).

Answer (score 0):

you are using a get request but you had defined it as a post request change it as `[httpget]`

Comment: I have changed as [httpget]. Still no response.

Comment: did you pass a value in request body ?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the string value in the request body and since it is marked as a HttpPost method, it has to be a Post call from the client.

Additionally, check if you are indeed sending the value in the request body. The content type should be coming in correctly for FromBody to work and map the primitive type.

I suggest you go through the answer of this question.

[WebApi POST works without [FromBody]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076070/webapi-post-works-without-frombody)